# Please someone explain the "opinion" close rules

Tags: support

I do not understand why [this thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23372/obtaining-sex-with-lies-and-rape) will only generate opinions, not answers? Because no-one knows the answer, or because I expressed an opinion in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I had to pick a close reason, I would have gone with **unclear what you're asking**. Good philosophical questions narrow down dilemma to a refined point. In this case, it's very difficult to tell what distinction you are trying to draw between someone who disguises themselves for the purpose of obtaining sex and someone who lies verbally instead. The unsourced Jed Rubenfeld quote of a sentence fragment doesn't help. In fact the whole mention of rape seems a red herring if I read the question correctly. What you really are asking about is the distinction (if any) between deceitful actions and deceitful words.

One way that the question *is* opinion-based is that you failed to specify an ethical framework. From the tags, I'm guessing you are interested in [Peter Singer's view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_Ethics). But you don't seem to engage with that book or any other [approach to applied ethics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_ethics#Modern_approach). All the systems of ethics that I know condemn deceit unless special circumstances intervene, but your question doesn't suggest any particular reason for not following the general rule of honesty.

Comment: ok thanks for the in depth answer - and yes i haven't yet engaged with the question much, but i asked the question so that i could ! i feel that the users of this site aren't stupid, or mean, but that they lack sympathy for people that ask questions

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it was closed as an opinion-based question either. I voted to close it because you were asking about whether a particular set of actions fit the definition of a particular word, which is just a definition, and the community has decided that questions that are only about definitions (especially about non-technical terms) are off-topic. There probably is one or more interesting philosophical questions closely related though.

I would also point out though that using profanity, even if you remove "*" out on of the characters, doesn't win you points.

Answer (score -1):

Someone still needs to explain if "opinion" - is something an "opinion" question if it will likely generate opinion, or if there's no clear answer in the literature, of if it is worded as if an opinion was being asked for, or what?

It's not clear.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: not very helpful "invite sharing experiences over opinions
insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references" any question that does not ask for an opinion can easily be rewritten that way :/

Comment: i do not understand how people are using that to rule to downvote or close my questions. i suspect that that the vote isn't being used in fair minded way

Comment: You've asked before for an explanation for downvotes on your posts. It has been explained to you. Please don't add several new questions that in the end boil down to the same thing. If you don't understand the previous explanation, ask for clarification or give it a rest.

Comment: i'm not just asking about my questions, thanks